# Error in function loop for

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I tried to write a program that takes two of the users and calculates the sum of the numbers between them (plus their own).
But I encountered an error!
it's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ForLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum =0;
        System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean firsttest;
        if(firsttest = myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int firstNumber = myScanner.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
                boolean secondtest;
                if(secondtest = myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    int secondNumber = myScanner.nextInt();
                    for(firstNumber ; firstNumber <= secondNumber ; firstNumber++) {
                        sum = sum + firstNumber ;
                    }
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Second number is not correct format.");
                }
        }else {
            System.out.println("first number is not correct format.");
        }
            System.out.println("total= " + sum);
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error on token "firstNumber", ++ expected after this token

at ForLoop.main(ForLoop.java:16)
```

Comment: Also, don't try to **run** your code if it doesn't even **compile**. Read the compiler errors, and fix them all, and then only start running your code.

Comment: Also, make sure to initialize the for loop control variable.

Comment: @Ao it is initialized

Comment: But the error hapend in line 16!!!

Comment: We cannot see line numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the first part of the for loop here. The value is already defined, and initialized `int firstNumber = myScanner.nextInt();`

Therefore, you want

```
for( ; firstNumber <= secondNumber ; firstNumber++) {
    sum = sum + firstNumber ;
}
```

Which looks odd, so try a while loop

```
while(firstNumber <= secondNumber)   {
    sum = sum + (firstNumber++);
}
```

Also, `sum += firstNumber++` works too

Comment: It did. But how?
If you can explain this...Thank

Comment: The three sections of a for loop are optional. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for(firstNumber ; firstNumber <= secondNumber ; firstNumber++)
```

to

```
for(; firstNumber <= secondNumber ; firstNumber++)
```

Comment: I actually want to start the numbers from the first number. Will this code do that?

Comment: It will. Why not try it and see?